# Javascript : one function , many divs

Tags: javascript, html

***OUTLOOK:***

I have a website which has a page called questions.html . In the page , there are many questions with answers. Each question is a div element. The answers is also a div and are hidden initially and is visible only when a button is clicked.

***ATTEMPT & PROBLEM:***

I have done it successfully for one set of question and answer , but when I do the same for another set the whole system gets messy. When I click on the button on the second question div , the answer div of the first question div shows up. But I want the button on the second question div to open the answer div of the second question div.

*HTML :*

```
<div id = "question1">
   <div id = "answer1" style = "display:none;">This is the 1st answer</div>
   <button id = "button1" onClick = "show()">Click For Answer</button>
</div>

<div id = "question2">
   <div id = "answer2" style = "display:none;">This is the 1st answer</div>
   <button id = "button2" onClick = "show()">Click For Answer</button>
</div>
```

*JavaScript :*

```
function show()
{
   var div=document.getElementById("answer1");
   var button=document.getElementById("button1");
   div.style.display="block";
   button.style.display="none";
}
```

I also noticed that it happens because my variables `div` and `button` wont select the div with the next set of ids (answer2 and button2)

***MY APPROACH:***

So I thought of creating a new function for each set of question and answer div. But this seems very unprofessional.
So is there any other way?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: In general, you can pass parameters to functions ...

Comment: I didnt get you. Could you elaborate

Comment: you can also use **pure CSS**, or at least a nicer/cleaner HTML markup with just a couple of JS lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the IDs as arguments:

```
function show(answerID, buttonID)
{
   var div=document.getElementById(answerID);
   var button=document.getElementById(buttonID);
   div.style.display="block";
   button.style.display="none";
}
```

Then the HTML would be:

```
<div id = "question1">
   <div id = "answer1" style = "display:none;">This is the 1st answer</div>
   <button id = "button1" onClick = "show('answer1', 'button1')">Click For Answer</button>
</div>

<div id = "question2">
   <div id = "answer2" style = "display:none;">This is the 1st answer</div>
   <button id = "button2" onClick = "show('answer2', 'button2')">Click For Answer</button>
</div>
```

Comment: OMG! Completely forgot about parameters!. It works , thumbs up :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jQuery,

```js
$(".show-answer").on("click", function() {
  $(this).siblings(".answer").css("display", "block");
  $(this).css("display", "none");
});
```

```css
.answer {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question">
  <div class="answer">This is the 1st answer</div>
  <button class="show-answer">Click For Answer</button>
</div>

<div class="question">
  <div class="answer">This is the 1st answer</div>
  <button class="show-answer">Click For Answer</button>
</div>
```

Selection process becomes simple and HTML looks clean.

Answer (score 0):

use `previoussibling` to show answers div and pass `this` for button

**update** there is problem with `previoussibling` that it consider text as node also so i have provided a function in working demo that can be used to overcome that problem

```
function show(obj)
{
   var div=obj.previousSibling;
   var button=obj
   div.style.display="block";
   button.style.display="none";
}

<div id = "question1">
   <div id = "answer1" style = "display:none;">This is the 1st answer</div><button id = "button1" onClick = "show(this)">Click For Answer</button>
</div>


<div id = "question2">
   <div id = "answer2" style = "display:none;">This is the 1st answer</div><button id = "button2" onClick = "show(this)">Click For Answer</button>
</div>
```

```js
 function show(obj)
    {
      console.log(obj.previousSibling)
       var div=previousElementSibling(obj);
       var button=obj
       div.style.display="block";
       button.style.display="none";
    }

function previousElementSibling( elem ) {
     do {
         elem = elem.previousSibling;
        } 
     while ( elem && elem.nodeType !== 1 );
 return elem;
  }
```

```html
    <div id = "question1">
       <div id = "answer1" style = "display:none;">This is the 1st answer</div><button id = "button1" onClick = "show(this)">Click For Answer</button>
    </div>
    

    <div id = "question2">
       <div id = "answer2" style = "display:none;">This is the 1st answer</div><button id = "button2" onClick = "show(this)">Click For Answer</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please be careful with `previousSibling`, it might be a string too (which it actually is in OP's case). `previousElementSibling` would be better to make sure you really get an element.

Comment: this seems shorter , but on implementation I get no results. Could you improve the answer?

Comment: @Teemu yes that the problem  have given an hack :)

Comment: @A.B oops your code created a mess ! , all the elements go haywire. But anyway , thanks for an answer

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all that ID / class trickery,
also using inline JS is quite hard to maintain.

See this instead, where I've only used `class="qa"`

```js
var qa = document.getElementsByClassName("qa");
function show(){
  this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("DIV")[0].style.display = (this.clicked^=1) ? "block" : "none";
}
for(var i=0; i<qa.length; i++)
  qa[i].getElementsByTagName("BUTTON")[0].addEventListener("click", show, false);
```

```css
div.qa > div{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="qa">
  <div>This is the 1st answer</div>
  <button>Click For Answer</button>
</div>

<div class="qa">
  <div>This is the 1st answer</div>
  <button>Click For Answer</button>
</div>
```

You can even use **pure CSS** for this, by just replacing `button` with `a` and usign the `:target` pseudo selector

```css
div.qa > div{
  display:none;
}

div.qa > div:target{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="qa">
  <div id="one">This is the 1st answer</div>
  <a href="#one">Click For Answer</a>
</div>

<div class="qa">
  <div id="two">This is the 2nd answer</div>
  <a href="#two">Click For Answer</a>
</div>
```